# How can i calculate the total score of a tag?

Tags: support, tags, data-explorer

I'm really bad at SQL. I want to use SEDE to calculate the total question score of a tag, meaning add up all of the votes on questions in a tag.

So, for example, a new tag with questions voted 5, 2, 11, -3 would have a total score of 15.

Anyone know how to query this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe [this](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/238847/votes-per-tag?TagName=c#) should do it.

```
SELECT SUM(Score) AS TotalScore
FROM Posts
    INNER JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
    INNER JOIN Tags ON Tags.Id = PostTags.TagId
WHERE Tags.TagName = '##TagName##'
```

There are a couple caveats, like that I believe the tag name is case-sensitive, and I didn't bother to include tag synonyms. But that should be the gist of it. If `TotalScore` is `NULL`, that means the tag wasn't found.

Comment: Perfect! Nice and simple, and fast too.